# UIBarButtonItem when is pressed do nothing

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I need that when the Done button on my toolbar, that is an accessory view of a textfield, make the keyboard to be dismissed.

```
  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    var toolBar = UIToolbar()
    var buttonOnToolbar = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "dismiss")
    let arrayOfButtons = [buttonOnToolbar]
    toolBar.items = arrayOfButtons
    toolBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    return true
}

func dismiss(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println("cacca")
}
```

The function dismiss in just a tryout to see if something happens when the button is clicked. But when I press it nothing happens.
Moreover the toolbar, although I changed his color remains transparent.
 What is wrong?

EDIT: Solved, the UIToolbar didn't have a size.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the wrong selector:

```
dismiss
```

selects a method that takes no argument. But your method takes one argument:

```
func dismiss(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
```

So your selector must be like this:

```
dismiss:
```

E.g.

```
UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "dismiss:")
```